# Cuda Multiple GPUs: All GPUs the same model?

Tags: cuda, gpu, multi-gpu

Do all the GPUs on a multi-gpu cuda setup have to be the same model gpu using CUDA?

For instance, I have a Geforce 950 now.  If I got a few more cards, would they all have to be 950s?  (And if so, do I have to stay with the same manufacturer?)

---

An answer that showed how to control CUDA on each individual GPU (assuming that the GPUs are all CUDA with same compute level), and confirmed that I can buy different models of NVIDIA card (before I spend the $300) and install on the same CUDA install (since the CUDA tools are compiled on each individual machine), would be sufficient.

So, for example, an answer that showed me how to take a tensorflow .py script and run it on one of the, say, three GPUs I have on my board using the CUDA command in the answers below would also be good (for the sake of this question; I think I definitely have enough to work with now to figure out the answer).

I believe this is related to how the CUDA software deals with the hardware, and would be off topic on SuperUser; however I am happy to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is : you can handle every single different CUDA GPU you want.
Multiple different graphics cards and multiple different GPUs can be handled by your applications in CUDA, as far as you manage them.

Check the [CUDA Faq](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq), section "Hardware and Architecture", and the [Multi-GPU slide](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-multi-gpu.pdf), both official from Nvidia.

> Q: Does CUDA support multiple graphics cards in one system?
>
> Yes. Applications can distribute work across multiple GPUs. This is not done automatically, however, so the application has complete control. See the "multiGPU" example in the GPU Computing SDK for an example of programming multiple GPUs.

Comment: so the answer is no :)

Comment: Depends on how you see the asnwer. Going to edit this to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck running CUDA on a non-NVIDIA card, but it doesn't matter who actually makes it (EVGA, MSI, etc.).

This shall answer your questions (with examples of how to implement stuff):

http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-multi-gpu.pdf

Edited to add:

Short answer: it doesn't matter.  This isn't SLI.

Comment: Teach a man to fish...

The link clearly shows a function call "cudaSetDevice()" which does exactly what you think it does.  It doesn't care if device 1 is a 980ti and device 2 is a 270 from several years ago.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have to be the exact same card (model or manufacturer), but it's better (from a development perspective) if they have the same compute capability.

You have full control on work sharing using functions as cudaSetDevice and so on, as documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE)

Comment: I think the one who asks would appreciate to have quotes and/or links from/to external sources ;)

Comment: indeed. Added a link to runtime API documentation